# Regular link to URL in Foundation tabs

Tags: hyperlink, tabs, zurb-foundation

I am using Foundation 5.2.1 and I want to use vertical tabs for navigation.

```
<div class="small-1 column">
  <div class="languageTabs">
    <dl class="tabs vertical" data-tab>
      <dd><a href="/lang/uk">uk</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="/lang/ru">ru</a></dd>
      <dd><a href="/lang/en">en</a></dd>
    </dl>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is unusual here is that I use not links to sections like `href="#section1"` but links to external URL. When I click on any tab it becomes highlighted as active but no redirection to the specified URL happens.

Is there a way to make the links to external pages work with tabs in Foundation, or should I use something different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution. Strange that this was not documented anywhere.

All one needs is to remove `data-tab` attribute from the `<dl>` element.

Then links will work as usually.

Comment: This won't work with Foundation 6. The externally linked tab will work but the others do not.

Answer (score 3):

I've been looking to do something similar. If you need to link offsite or to another page of your app, You can use a onclick event on your `dd` element:

```
<dd onclick="location.href='http://google.com'"><a href="#">Google</a></dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

@BartoNaz's solution is no longer working in Foundation 6 — it looks like 
Zurb failed to separate presentation (I want something that looks like tabs) from function (I want to show and hide parts of a single page).

I don't like the verbosity of Bootstrap, but since it's more flexible, and doesn't get in the way of RESTful web design, I guess I'll have to go back to it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the same for Foundation 6, remove the `data-tabs` property from the `ul`

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tabs id="example-tabs">
```